# How to validate TinyMCE for character length in php?

Tags: php, validation, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am looking for a way to validate the length of characters in tinymce in php. I have checked many sites but all provide client side validation no help for server side validation so can any one help me how to do that in php.

tried validating text area but didn't work

```
<?php
 $body = $_POST['body'];
if (strlen($body) <100){
  // error message
  }
?>
<textarea name="body" id="mytextbody"></textarea><br />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline blockquote | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | jbimages | media"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What did you tried so far? Please edit your question!

Comment: @jogo as I said dear found no hints anywhere to do that ,besides trying validating textarea but it didn't work